# Trim Video like UIVideoEditorController

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I want to trim video using something like UIVideoEditorController.
But I can't change navigation bar or frames slider position.
Is there any way to customize UIVideoEditorController navigation bar or is there any custom controller like UIVideoEditorController?

Comment: Hey bogdan, did you find a way to customize UIVideoEditorController or find any alternatives to it? I am facing a similar issue

Comment: I've wrote my own controller. But for trim slider I've found https://github.com/andrei200287/SAVideoRangeSlider

Comment: UIVideoEditorController is not customizable

Comment: Thanks!. I think I'll also go that route.